# What will happen if I put cut vegetables or roasted peanuts in a Salzburger grain mill or a mock mill?

Tags: grains, peanuts, puree, milling

I am trying to use a grain mill for peanut butter, and also pureeing vegetables. Can this work?

Answer (score 6):

## Don't do it.

a] it won't work properly &

b] you'll ruin the machine. It is supposed to take bone-dry grain in the top, grind between two flat(ish) granite plates - actual millstones - & pour fresh-milled flour out of a spout. It will not only clog the mechanism & not pour through, it will ruin the millstones by getting them greasy &/or wet.

Don't ruin a €600 mill trying to do a job you could get a dedicated machine for €35 to do better.

Comment: I feel for you regarding your former mill...